# Report Viewer Expression

Tags: .net, reporting-services, reportviewer

Basically, I want to check if the value of field F1 is not empty. If the row not empty then I want to calculate F2 * F3

The following expression always print

```
 #Error 
=IIf(Fields!f1 ="" ,"" ,Fields!f2.Value* Fields!If3.Value)
```

Please help

Answer (score 2):

You must use the Val function.

```
=IIF(IsNumeric(Fields!f2.Value) and IsNumeric(Fields!If3.Value),
     Val(Fields!f2.Value)*Val(Fields!If3.Value),
     Nothing
)
```

`ReportViewer` is a pain. IIf always evaluate 2 parts (true and false).

Answer (score 0):

Go and check the field expression. if you have something like: sum(fieldName) you must replace it with fieldName

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help You http://awebthatworks.wordpress.com/2010/04/29/reportviewer-expressions-which-use-data-fields-show-as-error/