# this expression always print #Error

Tags: reporting-services, reportviewer

This expression always print #Error on my report

```
=IIF(ISNOTHING(Fields!f2.Value)," ", Fields!f2.Value* Fields!If3.Value)
```

Comment: I'd guess you are trying to multiply non-numeric data.  What are the data types of f2 and f3?

Comment: This question is for the answer of [Report Viewer Expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3087082/report-viewer-expression)

Answer (score 0):

The parameters to IIF are always evaluated regardless of the value of the test. Let's break up the expression to see what happens.

```
P1 = ISNOTHING(Fields!f2.Value) // this gets evaluated and "True" is the value
P2 = Fields!f2.Value * Fields!If3.Value // this gets evaluated and throws an #Error
Result = IIF(P1," ",P2) // this never gets evaluated because an error is already thrown
```

try this instead:

```
=IIF(ISNOTHING(Fields!f2.Value)," ", IIF(ISNOTHING(Fields!f2.Value),0, Fields!f2.Value) * Fields!If3.Value)
```

In this scenario, when f2 is null here's what happens:

```
P1 = ISNOTHING(Fields!f2.Value) // this gets evaluated and "True" is the value
P2 = IIF(P1,0, Fields!f2.Value) // this gets evaluated and 0 is the value
P3 = P2 * Fields!If3.Value // this gets evaluated and 0 is the value
Result = IIF(P1, " ", P3) // this gets evaluated and " " is the result
```

Comment: Does `SWITCH` also behave the same way? Is every clause in `SWITCH` evaluated too?

Comment: It works that way for IIF() because it is a function call. Just like any other function call, the parameters are evaluated and passed to the function. SWITCH() in SSRS is also a function call, so yes. All parameters will be evaluated every time.